# how can i dismiss keyboard using UITextInput protocol?

Tags: ios

i want dismiss the keyboard when i tap the done button. is there some functions in UITextInput protocol i can use to dismiss the keyboard?

thanks for answering, guys~

Answer (score 3):

It's pretty straight forward

```
[textField resignFirstResponder];
```

Comment: yeah, you should also make sure to allow your users to touch the background to make the textbox disappear... but that is more complicated